# Laravel Text doesn't show True/False, but 0/1

Tags: php, laravel

In the MySQL database, I use tinyint(1) so the validate field will either be 0 or 1. 
How can I edit this thrust below to make it able to display True or False instead of 0 or 1?

```
namespace App\Thrust;

use BadChoice\Thrust\Resource;
use BadChoice\Thrust\Fields\Link;
use BadChoice\Thrust\Fields\Text;
use BadChoice\Thrust\Fields\Email;
use BadChoice\Thrust\Fields\Gravatar;

class Requester extends Resource
{
    public static $model        = \App\Requester::class;
    public static $search       = ['name', 'email'];
    public static $defaultSort  = 'tickets_count';
    public static $defaultOrder = 'DESC';
public function fields()
    {
        return [
            Text::make('validate', 'Validate'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functionality which you're looking for is called [Type Casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

> The meaning of type casting is to use the value of a variable with
>   different data type. In other word typecasting is a way to utilize one
>   data type variable into the different data type. [Source](https://www.greycampus.com/codelabs/php/type-casting)

Example

```
$response = 1;

var_dump($response); // Output: int(1)
var_dump((bool)$response); // Output: bool(true)
```

Another example might be when you're building a function and withing it you're obtaining `1/0` value and if you want to return it as `boolean` type you can do it inside it. For example:

```
public function isValid((string) $query): boolean
{
    $result = some_check($query);
    return (boolean) $result;
}
```

Other possible data type conversions are:

```
(int), (integer) - cast to integer
(bool), (boolean) - cast to boolean
(float), (double), (real) - cast to float
(string) - cast to string
(array) - cast to array
(object) - cast to object
```

Comment: I tried using ```Text::make((boolean) 'ic_validate', 'Validate')``` but the field is empty now

Comment: @zy you should use `(boolean)` before `Text` like `(boolean)Text::make('validate', 'Validate'),`

Comment: I tried that too but cannot work. 'validate' is a column filled with 0/1. 'Validate' is name of the column. Is it because it is a table column so it cannot direct (boolean) assign to the variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can cast to boolean before showing
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting